# How to host ASP.NET application externally

Tags: iis

I have an ASP.NET 2.0 environment running locally. I am hosting out of port 81 since I already have an apache web server running on 80. As of the moment, I can successfully go to 192.168.1.102:81/TestApp and load up the test ASP.NET application I have built. I am now trying to host it outside of my network by going to mydomain.com:81/TestApp. Pretty self explanatory, but for some reason I am having some trouble accomplishing this. The error I get when going to mydomain.com:81/TestApp is that it is a broken link. The only place I know of that allows me to configure the IP Address for the IIS web server is in Web Site Identification in the IP Address textbox. I am trying to set my IIS web server to receive requests on port 81 for my domain. I already have my DNS records pointing to my external IP Address. Can someone clue me in on how to enable my IIS web server to receive requests from my domain (outside my network)? I'm looking for the httpd.conf of IIS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My goodness. Windows firewall was blocking it. Had to add an exception for port 81... Problem solved.

Comment: #thestrugglecontinues

Answer (score 1):

You need to set port forwarding in your (wireless/regular) router to forward port 81 coming from the outside, to your internal IP.

Comment: I have already done this and still no luck. I can already go to 192.168.1.102:81/TestApp. I tried doing a single port forward and that didn't work either. Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the domain name you are using reaches your machine? Can you get to Apache through it?